# How to export mysql database using laravel 4. for windows file system

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, phpmyadmin

I want to create a backup of my database by clicking a button, pls help me to take back up.

Answer (score 0):

To backup a database you can run `mysqldump -u root -p databasename > databasefile.sql`

If you would like an interface rather than interacting with your database via the command-line, you can use a tool like phpmyadmin.

Backing up your database should also back up your L4 migrations.